# Values for fields added to a HTML form with jQuery are not available in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a form where the users have the option to add as many people as they want to a database.
JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/atyclb/qyammbrw/ (the code is stripped down to a minimum)

The php code is basic just to view the name array:

```
<?php
    $personname=$_POST['personname'];
    print_r ($personname);
?>
```

It always returns an array with a single element, no matter how many fields I add with jQuery.
However, If I manually add the fields to the HTML form, it works and returns all values.

Comment: if you do `var_dump($_POST)` what do you get?

Comment: I get only the first name - ["personname"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "John" }

Comment: Can you post your jQuery?

Comment: Everything is in the fiddle above

Comment: @Octav I have added only a submitt button to your code and then test it and it works fine

Comment: I tested your code as well, works fine. How are you submitting the data?

Comment: Thanks! You were really helpful testing the code. I had a noob HTML error in my not-stripped-down code - the FORM tag was closed twice: hence the error "end tag for element FORM which is not open" and not processing the remaining input fields after the first ocurrence of </form>

Answer (score 0):

I had an HTML error in my not-stripped-down code - the FORM tag was closed twice: hence the error "end tag for element FORM which is not open" and not processing the remaining input fields after the first occurrence of < / form>

Comment: Glad you got it figure out! In the future, don't strip down your code - it makes it impossible for us to help you. Removing/changing passwords and sensitive information is fine, but you should really post all of the relevant code as is, there is no need to strip down HTML.